# Convert List of numbers as string to a single Integer

Tags: python, for-loop, join, concatenation

I'm trying to convert a list to a single integer using two methods:

`for` loop works fine and gives me the integer

```
>>> a_list = "123456789"
>>> a_list = list(a_list)
>>> b_int = ""
>>> for num in a_list:
    ... b_int += num
    ...
>>> print(int(b_int))

123456789
```

however `join()` returns a ValueError

```
>>> a_list = "123456789"
>>> c_int = ""
>>> c_int.join(a_list)
>>> print(int(c_int))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(int(c_int))
          ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Why does `join()` returns a ValueError? It was suggested in a number of different posts as a better solution.

Comment: `a_list` is **not** a list of numbers but just a single string of numeric characters

Comment: naming string variables `a_list` or `b_int` is a recipe for disaster. Try using meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the `ValueError` is that you are calling `int` to an empty string and not to the `join` one. String are immutables so you need always to re-assign the result.

```
a_list = "123456789"
c_int = ""
c_int = c_int.join(a_list) # <- 

print(int(c_int))
```

By the way `int(a_list)` does the same.

Comment: Ohh god you're right! I completely missed it!

Answer (score 0):

As the string is a string it cannot be "joined" to a number, but if the string contains numbers it can be cast to numbers and then reduced

```
list("123456789")
Out[6]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
[int(x) for x in list("123456789")]
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
sum([int(x) for x in list("123456789")])
Out[8]: 45
```